# Declaring multiple prototype definitions

Tags: javascript

In [Mary live-codes a JavaScript game from scratch](http://vimeo.com/105955605), Mary Rose Cook uses the following code to show a simple JavaScript program:

```js
var Game = function(canvasId) {
 this.WIDTH = 200;
 this.HEIGHT = 200;
 this.boxX = 10;

 var canvas = getCanvas(canvasId);
 sizeCanvas(canvas, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
 var drawingContext = getContext(canvas);

 this.createEntities();

 var self = this;
 this.startTick(function() {
 self.update();
 self.draw(drawingContext);
 });
};

Game.prototype = {
 x: 10,
 startTick: function(fn) {
 var tick = function() {
   fn();
   requestAnimationFrame(tick);
 };

 requestAnimationFrame(tick);
 },

 createEntities: function() {
 this.bullets = [];
 this.ship = new Ship(this);

 this.invaders = [];
 for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
   this.invaders.push(new Invader(this, {
   x: 20 + 20 * (i % 8),
   y: 20 + 20 * (i % 3)
   }));
 }
 },

 shoot: function(center) {
 this.bullets.push(new Bullet(this.game, center));
 },

 update: function() {
 this.ship.update();

 for (var i = 0; i < this.invaders.length; i++) {
   this.invaders[i].update();
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
   this.bullets[i].update();
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
   if (entitiesColliding(this.ship, this.bullets[i])) {
   this.ship.color = "#f00";
   }
 }
 },

 draw: function(drawingContext) {
 drawingContext.clearRect(0, 0, this.WIDTH, this.HEIGHT);
 this.ship.draw(drawingContext);

 for (var i = 0; i < this.invaders.length; i++) {
   this.invaders[i].draw(drawingContext);
 }

 for (var i = 0; i < this.bullets.length; i++) {
   this.bullets[i].draw(drawingContext);
 }
 }
};

var sizeCanvas = function(canvas, width, height) {
 canvas.width = width;
 canvas.height = height;
};

var getContext = function(canvas) {
 return canvas.getContext('2d');
};

var getCanvas = function(canvasId) {
 return document.getElementById(canvasId);
};

var Ship = function(game) {
 this.game = game;
 this.size = { x: 10, y: 10 };
 this.color = "#000";
 this.center = { x: game.WIDTH / 2, y: game.HEIGHT - this.size.y };

 this.inputter = new Inputter();
};

Ship.prototype = {
 update: function() {
 if (this.inputter.isDown(37)) { // left
   this.center.x--;
 } else if (this.inputter.isDown(39)) {
   this.center.x++;
 }
 },

 draw: function(drawingContext) {
 drawRectangleForObject(this, drawingContext);
 }
};

var drawRectangleForObject = function(obj, drawingContext) {
 drawingContext.fillStyle = obj.color;
 drawingContext.fillRect(obj.center.x, obj.center.y, obj.size.x, obj.size.y);
};

var Invader = function(game, center) {
 this.game = game;
 this.size = { x: 10, y: 10 };
 this.center = center;
 this.color = "#000";
};

Invader.prototype = {
 patrolSpeedX: 0,
 patrolPositionX: 0,
 update: function() {
 if (this.patrolPositionX <= 0) {
   this.patrolSpeedX = 0.5;
 } else if (this.patrolPositionX >= 20) {
   this.patrolSpeedX = -0.5;
 }

 this.patrolPositionX += this.patrolSpeedX;
 this.center.x += this.patrolSpeedX;

 if (Math.random() < 0.005) {
   this.game.shoot({ x: this.center.x, y: this.center.y });
 }
 },

 draw: function(drawingContext) {
 drawRectangleForObject(this, drawingContext);
 }
};

var Inputter = function() {
 var keyState = {};

 window.onkeydown = function(e) {
 keyState[e.keyCode] = true;
 };

 window.onkeyup = function(e) {
 keyState[e.keyCode] = false;
 };

 this.isDown = function(keyCode) {
 return keyState[keyCode] === true;
 };
};

function Bullet(game, center) {
 this.game = game;
 this.size = { x: 4, y: 4 };
 this.color = "#000";
 this.center = center;
 this.vector = { x: Math.random() - 0.5, y: Math.random() };
};

Bullet.prototype = {
 update: function() {
 this.center.x += this.vector.x;
 this.center.y += this.vector.y;
 },

 draw: function(drawingContext) {
 drawRectangleForObject(this, drawingContext);
 }
};

var entitiesColliding = function(e1, e2) {
 return !(e1.center.x + e1.size.x / 2 < e2.center.x - e2.size.x / 2 ||
    e1.center.y + e1.size.y / 2 < e2.center.y - e2.size.y / 2 ||
    e1.center.x - e1.size.x / 2 > e2.center.x + e2.size.x / 2 ||
    e1.center.y - e1.size.y / 2 > e2.center.y + e2.size.y / 2);
};

new Game('canvas')
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

I changed how she defines Game.prototype to be something like this instead:

```
Game.prototype.startTick = function(fn) {...snip...}
Game.prototype.createEntities = function() {...snip...}
Game.prototype.shoot = function(center) {...snip...}
```

Q: Is that considered bad style, to have separate prototype declarations as opposed to one giant object definition?

Answer (score 3):

Not a bad style  at all. Unless you create an instance of the object before defining any of thr property. For ex.

```
Game.prototype.startTick = function(fn) {...snip...}
    new Game('canvas')
        Game.prototype.createEntities = function() {...snip...}
```

Else, its all the same.

Comment: actually, you can define protos later, you just (obviously) can't use something that doesn't exists.

Comment: Yes thats right , thats what i wanted to explain.. Thanx dandavis